# What is the AXA Schengen Insurance office phone number?

Tags: schengen, insurance

I made the payment for a Schengen (Europe Travel) visa at the AXA-Schengen website, but haven't yet got (it has been five hours) any insurance documents by email. How long should I wait? They don't have any phone numbers listed on their website, and say that we should email them first. This is pretty ridiculous. If I made a payment, I should get my documents immediately. Please, does anyone have a phone number I can call?

Comment: Your lucky.in my case is they have not send me the refund for almost 4 months now. I called the number you provided and they said they only have do assistant but thwy dont hav number or cant contact the axa for refund! I feel so much that this is a scam. They already email me back that they will refund me in september since august flight was cancelled but its november now! :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How long should I wait?

According to the [FAQs on their website](https://www.axa-schengen.com/en/FAQ), you should have received the insurance certificate immediately after payment:

> Q: How do you send the proof/certificate of insurance? 
>   A: The mandatory insurance certificate is sent by e-mail immediately after payment. You just need to print it.

Since it's not uncommon for auto-generated emails to end up in some sort of spam folder, be sure to check there too. Your mail provider may have flagged the email as 'suspicious'.

> Please, does anyone have a phone number I can call?

It looks like the AXA Schengen travel insurance is mainly an online-only business, as it can only be purchased the website. Hence, it's no surprise all customer service related queries are routed through `info.schengen@axa-schengen.com`. There is a mention of an emergency contact number, but apparently only listed on the actual certificate.

That being said, I see two obvious options if you still want to try and phone the company:

1. AXA Assistance is represented by Inter Partner Assistance. You can grab their phone number from [their website](http://www.ip-assistance.be/nl/contact) (sorry, in Dutch, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the phone numbers). You'll see that the address mentioned there matches the one listed on the AXA Assistance contact page. As a matter of fact: `http://www.ip-assistance.com/` basically just redirects to `http://www.axa-assistance.com/`.  **You may contact Inter Partner Assistance on +3225500400**.
2. Try one of the many [AXA offices in Europe](http://www.axa.com/en/group/axaworld/europe/). Not sure which one would be best to call though. Anything Schengen related is probably out of scope for the local offices and I wouldn't be surprised if they'll just refer you to the aforementoned email address (that is, if they refer you at all).

Last but not least, and perhaps handy for future readers:

> Any communication with AXA Schengen (written, verbal or electronic) may be in French, Dutch, English or Spanish.

Comment: Oh my gosh, YOU NAILED IT! :) The website link you provided (http://www.ip-assistance.com/) is what I went to, and got this number: + 32 2 550 04 00. The automated response is in (I think) French, which I do not understand, so I just pressed 1 until I got a person on the line :) She sent me my documents right away. Thank you so much! This was a fantastic answer.

Comment: @user1096863: Glad to hear that worked out for you and that you're all sorted out. :) You phoned a Belgium number (Brussels, to be precise), so there's a good chance the automated response was in French. It's either that or Dutch, but that would sound quite differently. Happy travels!

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone in the future, you can access your documents from the AXA Schengen website at any time.

For "name of beneficiary" put your last name, and for "policy number" put the order reference (it begins with SCHE....) in the email that you got when you paid. If you didn't get the order email immediately then your payment either didn't go through or the email got caught in a spam filter!